# Realtime FireBase Database rules - where is auth.token located in a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I wanted to know where a auth.token variable is located on a normal js fetch request.

For example, I have these rules:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.token=='tokenhere'",
    ".write": "auth.token=='tokenhere'",
  }
}
```

Like a simple password system,

now I wanted to know where that `auth.token` would go in a fetch request in order to succeed these rules.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Firebase REST API then you would pass the users ID token in the "auth" query parameter. E.g. https://fire.database.io/path?auth=ey... this works if you are using Firebase auth. You cannot pass custom data to that API

Comment: @Dharmaraj doing this returns an error: Could not parse auth token.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass along custom information to the security rules. The only things available in your rules are:

1. The path that the user is reading from or writing to.
2. The data that the user is writing, if this is a write operation.
3. The `auth` variable, if there is an authenticated user.

So if you want to test anything in your security rules, it'll have to be in one of these fields.

For example, if I want to store data that can only be accessed if the user knows some specific secret (like a password), I typically encoded that secret into the path to that data.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "correcthorsebatterystaple": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
    }
  }
}
```

With the above rules the user can only read/write the data if they somehow know the secret "correcthorsebatterystaple" value.